# What is the main functionality of do_action?

Tags: wordpress

How does this work?
Here is the code.

```
<?php do_action('antreas_before_footer'); ?>
```

Here "antreas" is the current theme name.

Answer (score 1):

The theme developer created a hook for you to plug your own functionality or code without having to edit the theme files.  The proper way to handle this would be to create a child theme and write a function for that named hook in your functions.php.

Read more about this here:
https://themeshaper.com/2009/05/25/action-hooks-wordpress-child-themes/